# Why do questions sometimes not appear immediately on the site after asking?

Tags: support, bug, questions

I saw that sometimes when I ask a new question it does not appear on the site immediately. It takes sometimes at least 2-3 minutes before appearing but still got a view. I keep on refreshing the filtered list of new questions.

Is the question sent to moderator approval first, and then it will appear?
Sometimes I found a quick edit and quick answer by people above 50k reputation even when the question appears after 2-3 minutes.

I just saw it, it happened on Puzzling Meta also, but this was not the case on Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow Meta.

[image]

As you can see there are 2 views on the question.

[image]

But you can see it is not there in the newest question list. This time it took 5 minutes and still did not appear.

Answer (score 4):

### Caching.

It's always caching. https://shouldiblamecaching.com/ That explains why you don't immediately see the newest questions list in its most final version. (If you keep that page open in another tab while you post a new question, you will see a little "(1)" appear which, when you click on it, shows your question as the newest one.)

> Is the question sent to moderator approval first, and then it will appear?

No.

> Sometimes I found a quick edit and quick answer by people above 50k reputation even when the question appears after 2-3 minutes.

Maybe those people were keeping the question list open so that they could immediately spot updates to it?

[image: what it looks like in the tabs list]
[image: what it looks like on the front page of the site]

The above images show how the tab appears with the "(1)", and how it looks on the front page of the site if you've kept that tab open.

Comment: I don't know it does not happen on StackOverflow but only stack puzzle site, also there is no (1) icon I have ever found, + I will try to look for it your advice when I ask a new question. this question appeared to me after 5 minutes. I also tried new incognito mode on chrome but it was the same case there also.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli Added some images to show what I mean about the (1) thing.

Comment: Ok, I will try this new tab trick ( should the answer be a trick) but I have never noticed it and why I need to go to the new tab to look for the newest question. It should appear in the list of newest questions (newest category). I tried to click on newest category several times refresh the list and everything but the question never appeared and after 5 minutes it appeared automatically. This thing happened to me every time I asked a new question.

Comment: Caching is a very normal thing on a lot of websites. I'm not tech-savvy at all and even I know that.

Comment: I know about caching and I am a web developer by profession. the caching problem doesn't happen in incognito mode. Also, If it was a caching problem then it should never be clear automatically until and unless I clean my cache. the new question should never appear. I will look for the cache when I ask a new question I will clear it immediately and If I face the same problem again I will come back to you.

Comment: I *was* a programmer and I somewhat agree to say that it's due to caching. It's not always the case of browser cache, it could be the database caching. That means all updates may not be immediately shown, it may come in a batch (let's say SE will push the update to clients every 30 secs -- again, it could be they actively send the updates to all clients or could be the client makes an update requests once in a while). The details are not important and this issue.. is really not worth an issue.

Comment: @athin yes i know there is database server side cache to apart from client side cache like browerser but if that is the case then it is a bug and it needs to be resolved...

Comment: @SayedMohdAli actually not always, it may be the intended implementation as it may act as a load balancer or traffic limiter.

Comment: @athin but this is not a small business, it is StackExchange, they must be having a lot of servers and very high configuration, they can easily deal with it.  have you ever saw any big MNC websites face these types of issues?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I don't no why but I am not facing the problem anymore.  I posted the question today and it appears immediately so this question is not needed anymore...